# excel min of a subset of a range

Tags: excel, min

I have an excel sheet with two columns of interest Year and Donations. The year values are 2008,2009,2010 etc...

I would like to get the minimum of all donations for 2009. I have tried

MIN(IF(Year="2009",Donations,"")

The problem with this is for years other than 2009 it falls to "" and hence the min is 0.

Is there a different function I should be using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula you have is correct.  MIN will ignore text.  A couple of things to check:

Make sure the data in Years is really text.  If it's a number, you need to remove the quotes around 2009 or it won't find anything.

Make sure you're entering the formula with Control+Shift+Enter, and not just Enter.  Excel will put curly braces around the formula in the formula bar indicating it's an array formula.

Make sure you're not actually getting the correct answer.  That is, make sure there are no entries of zero for 2009.  Seems unlikely you would record a donation of zero, but it's worth a look.

If your Year data is actually text, maybe because it's imported, then it's possible the Donations data is text too.  If that's the case use

```
MIN(IF(Year="2009",Donations*1,""))
```

The *1 will force the text to a number if possible.

Comment: Ok, CTrl+Shift+Enter did it. Not sure why that is important but it did it. And, I learned something new. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Enter this as an array formula (press ctrl-shift-enter rather than just enter to make it an array)

```
=MIN(IF(<YearRange>=2009,<ValueRange>,""))
```

Comment: i've tested it, works for me.  be sure you enter it as an array formula (ctrl-shift-enter). Also if your years are entered as text rather than numbers it will return 0: modify your formual to  `=MIN(IF(VALUE(A1:A4)=2010,B1:B4,""))` to test this

Answer (score 0):

Create a pivot table with Year as a row and Donations as Data (choose the Minimum option).

Comment: I wish I had that capability. I am limited to what I can do with this sheet. I can't create new ranges, use pivot etc...Any other ideas