# Excel Min() of certain numbers in a range

Tags: excel, min

I'm looking to get the min() of a specific set of numbers in a range

eg min of all the blue cells in the screen below with the answer being output in E74

[excelscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFP2S.png)

Currently i'm using =MIN(E2,E10,E18,E26,E34,E42,E50,E58,E66)

But i was hoping for something more robust as the range grows without having to manually include the extra cells (E66+)

I was thinking something like minif(E2:E66,A2:A66, test if a# is not empty) but couldnt figure a way to make it work.

any better option overall or is there a solution using minif?

many thanks!

AL

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=minif&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=bF29WNmPCqjdgAb80LOQAw#q=minif+excel&* -> http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2011/07/27/finding-min-if-or-max-if-in-excel/

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=MINIFS($E$2:$E$1000,$A$2:$A$1000,"<>""")
```

Comment: tried this plus your ABOVE approach, but both returned 0, could be a google sheets things, could work in excel but can't confirm. thanks very much anyways, similar to solution below, would be nice to have it work without need for the array as per minif.

Comment: I've test this in google sheets and it works. Create duplicate spreadsheet, remove private information's and post a link.

Comment: had to update to limit range less then my outpout rows to avoid the circle dependency http://imgur.com/a/L4vpX

Comment: Yes, either put in different column or up to row you've using formula.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach based on empty cell ABOVE your desired values in E column:

```
=MINIFS($E$2:$E$1000,$E$1:$E$999,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I found a solution myself although using min(If()) rather then minif
thanks to... [excel min of a subset of a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134005/excel-min-of-a-subset-of-a-range?rq=1)

In my case it would look like

(MIN(IF(A2:A73<>"",E2:E73,""))) with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER for the array

=ArrayFormula(MIN(IF(A2:A73<>"",E2:E73,"")))

Thankfully as I add rows above my output cells the formula updates to include the new rows so happy days!

Thanks folks

AL